# Java add milliseconds to a millisecond timestamp omit weekends and holidays

Tags: java, javafx, timestamp

I am a beginner and I wanted to **add milliseconds to a java timestamp (in milliseconds) and get the resulting time in milliseconds** for further manipulation. I had attempted to do that by incrementing the timestamp each millisecond and checking if it landing to a holiday or weekend then I skip that day. Its not very wise to do that. Takes forever. Is there someone who has already invented the wheel?

*Here is my poor and very bad code (**Do not use this, takes ages**)*

```
public static class businessdays {

        public static long addWorkingTime(long timestamp, long milliseconds){

            for (int i=0;i<milliseconds;i ++){
                long test_timestamp = timestamp + 1;
                while (isHoliday(test_timestamp)){
                    System.out.println("isHoliady");
                    timestamp += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //jump weekend or holiday
                    test_timestamp += (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                }               
                timestamp += i;
            }

            return timestamp;           
        }

        private static boolean isHoliday(long timestamp){
            List<String> holidays = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("01/01,05/01,06/01,10/20,12/12,12/25,12/26".split(",")));
            SimpleDateFormat dw = new SimpleDateFormat("u"); //date of the week - 1 - 7
            SimpleDateFormat dd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd"); //1 - 30/31
            SimpleDateFormat dm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM"); //1 - 12
            Date test_timeDate = new Date(timestamp);
            String date = dm.format(test_timeDate)+"/"+dd.format(test_timeDate); //MM/dd
            String doweek = dw.format(test_timeDate);
            if (holidays.contains(date) || doweek.contains("6") || doweek.contains("7")){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Adding milliseconds is a way to achieve something. Not an end goal. What's your end goal?

Comment: Like JB Nizet said - what are you trying to achieve? Is it that important that a timestamp is accurate to a millisecond (which it will never be anyway)? 
Can you not check say every second and then decide to use or not use the timestamp? If you're on Windows for example (which is NOT a real-time operating system), the milliseconds in your application may be quite different from the 'real life' milliseconds i.e. don't expect absolute accuracy from the milliseconds - if you do, you'll be disappointed!

Comment: My end goal is to have a function that will when given the current timestamp and I add like 28 or more hours, I should get the deadline calculated with business days

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Calendar class will let you operate in days, which might be preferable. Milliseconds tend to be a naive choice for date processing, because not all days have the same number of milliseconds. Every so often leap seconds are inserted, and the days at each end of a daylight savings period have a whole hour less or more than the usual 24.

```
final static int DAY_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
static String hols[] = new String[] { "01/01", "05/01", "06/01", "10/20", "12/12", "12/25", "12/26" };

public static long addWorkingTime(long timestamp, long milliseconds)
{
    // Get a calendar from a timestamp.
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    while (isHoliday(cal)) cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    // Count off the days in milliseconds.
    int days = (int)(milliseconds / DAY_MILLIS);
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        while (isHoliday(cal)) cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    // Apply the leftover from milliseconds if there is any.
    milliseconds = milliseconds - days * DAY_MILLIS;
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, milliseconds);
    while (isHoliday(cal)) cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    // Return a timestamp from a calendar.
    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
}

static boolean isHoliday(Calendar cal)
{
    int dow = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dow == Calendar.SATURDAY || dow == Calendar.SUNDAY) return true;
    String mmdd = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").format(cal.getTime());
    return Arrays.binarySearch(hols, mmdd) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver John Bickers

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- Don't use milliseconds for tracking working days and holidays.
- Use `LocalDate` class, along with `DayOfWeek`, `Month`, and `MonthDay` classes.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the modern *java.time* classes rather than the terrible old legacy classes such as `Calendar` & `Date`.

## `MonthDay`

> new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("01/01,05/01,06/01,10/20,12/12,12/25,12/26".split(",")))

Instead of strings, use [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class for these values. Using objects makes your code more self-documenting, ensures valid values, and provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
List< MonthDay > monthDayHolidays = List.of( 
    MonthDay.of( Month.JANUARY , 1 ) ,
    MonthDay.of( Month.DECEMBER , 25 ) ,
    MonthDay.of( Month.DECEMBER , 26 ) 
) ;
```

That approach for defining holidays in incomplete. Some holidays are set by date, but many are relative, such as 3rd Monday of a certain month.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

### Math

You can add or subtract days by calling `plus…` & `minus…` methods on `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate later = ld.plusDays( 11 ) ;
```

You can skip weekends (Saturday/Sunday) by defining an [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) of [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum objects.

```
Set< DayOfWeek > weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
```

Check your next date against that set.

```
if( weekend.contains( localDate.getWeekOfDay() ) ) {
    nextWorkingDay.plusDays( 1 ) ;
}
```

Easier way is to add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This makes available a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation that skips Sat/Sun: [`nextWorkingDay()`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#nextWorkingDay--).

```
LocalDate nextWorkingDay = 
    localDate.with( 
        org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay() 
    ) 
;
```

### Filter

You must compare each date against your lists of holidays.

We can ask the `LocalDate` for its `MonthDay`.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.from( localDate ) ;
```

See if that `MonthDay` is present in our list.

```
if( monthDayHolidays.contains( md ) ) 
{ … skip … }
```

## Milliseconds

If you must start with a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC, parse that as a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( … ) ;
```

To get a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. A few moments after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Apply this `ZoneId` to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment as the `Instant`, same point on the timeline, but viewed through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract just the date portion, without the time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).